# issues for a code snippet to handle the input file

Tags: perl

I am studying a Perl program, which includes the following segment for handling an input file. I  do not understand what is `s/^\s+//;`  used for?  Moreover, what are '|' and '||' stand for in `open(FILE, "cat $fileName |") || die "could not open file";`

```
open(FILE, "cat $fileName |") || die "could not open file";
while (<FILE>)
{
    s/^\s+//;
    my @line = split;
    if ($line[0]!~ /\:/) {$mark=0}
    my $var = $line[$mark];
       ## some other code
}
```

Comment: this code is quite odd...  the first s/^\s+//; doesn't appear to be doing anything at all.. and in fact i'd think it would throw an error...  the || stands for OR.  and | i THINK (been a while since ive used perl so i could be wrong) simply means to decrypt the file that's being opened.  Through a quick google search I found: http://www.rocketaware.com/perl/perlfunc/open.htm

Comment: @Justin: The `s///` is operating on the default argument (`$_`) so it is doing something, the argumentless `split` call is doing the same and the `while(<FILE>)` will assign to `$_`.

Comment: Also, ":" is not special in regular expressions, and so does not need the preceeding "\"

Comment: And `if ($line[0]!~ /\:/) {$mark=0}` is better written as `$mark = 0 if $line[0] !~ /:/;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the confusion is that the developer is using the default variable, `$_`. Many Perl commands (I would say about 1/3 of them) act upon `$_` when you don't specify the name of the variable in the function. For example, these are syntactically the same:

```
my $uppercase_name = uc($_);
my $uppercase_name = uc;
```

In both cases, the `uc` function will print the string in the `$_` variable in upper case characters. In fact, even the `print` statement uses the `$_` variable. Again, these are both the same:

```
print $_;
print;
```

It's frowned upon to use the default variable in newer Perl scripts because it doesn't add clarity to the program and it doesn't make the program faster. I've rewritten the same code snippet you used in order to show the missing `$_` variable. It might make the code easier to understand:

```
open(FILE, "cat $fileName |") || die "could not open file";
while ($_ = <FILE>)
{
    $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
    my @line = split $_;
    if ($line[0] !~ /\:/) {
        $mark = 0;
    }
    my $var = $line[$mark];
       ## some other code
}
```

Notice that the `while` statement is putting the value of the line read into the `$_` variable and that the *substitute* command (the `s/^\s+//`) is also operating on the `$_` variable. I hope that clarifies the code a bit for you.

Now for your questions:

> _[W]hat do '|' and '||' stand for?

The `||` means *or* as in do *this or that*. In practice, the *or* can be thought of as an if statement:

```
if (not open(FILE, "cat $fileName |")) {
   die "could not open file";
}
```

That is, if the open statement failed, then execute the `die` statement. If the open statement did manage to open the file, then don't execute the `die` statement.

In Perl, you now see `or` instead of `||` in cases like this:

```
open(FILE, "cat $fileName |") or die "could not open file";
```

which makes the meaning a bit more obvious: *Open the file, or kill the program.*

The single pipe (`|`) at the end of the file name means execute the command in the open statement (the `cat $filename`) and read from the output of this command. Imagine something like this:

```
open (COMMAND, "java -jar foo.war|") or die "Can't execute 'java -jar foo.war'";
```

Now, I'm running the command `java -jar foo.war` and using its output in my Perl script.

You can do this the other way around too:

```
open (MAIL, "|mail $recipient") or die "Can't mail $recipient";
print MAIL "Dear $recipient\n\n";
print MAIL "I hope everything is well.\n";
print MAIL "Sincerely,\n\nDavid";
close MAIL;
```

I'm now opening the command `mail $recipient` and writing to it with the `print` statements. In this case, I'm emailing `$recipient` with a simple message.

> I do not understand what is s/^\s+//; used for?

In the original program, it was on a line by itself:

```
s/^\s+//;
```

I've added the *missing variable* which should help clarify it a bit:

```
 $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
```

This is the Substitute command in Perl. It's taking the `$_` variable and substituting the regular expression `^\s+` with nothing. If you don't understand what are regular expressions, you should take a look at the [Perldoc tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) on the subject. Basically, this is removing all spaces, tabs, and other forms of *white space* from the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the documentation for the various functions in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

This code will open a file for reading, by the rather circumspect way of piping from `cat` instead of simply opening the file. The `|` means that the shell command `cat` is piped to the open command, and our file handle will read from the output.

`||` is simply or. Open the pipe, and if that fails, the program dies.

`while(<FILE>)` will read through every line of the input and assign each line to `$_`. That line is then used implicitly in the substitution and split below. I.e. `s/^\s+//` is equal to `$_ =~ s/^\s+//`, and `split` is equal to `split(' ', $_)`.

```
s/^\s+//
```

Will remove leading whitespace. The split will split each line on whitespace, and the elements are stored in the array `@line`.

Because of the use of implicit split on whitespace, the stripping the leading whitespace with `s/^\s+//` is not really needed, as that is done automatically.

If the first element does not contain a colon `:`, `$mark` is set to 0. Otherwise, it is not set, and will presumably use the value from the previous iteration, since it is not defined inside the loop. Finally, `$var` is initialized as element number `$mark`, which is either 0 or whatever.

ETA: As a rather insidious oops: If `$mark` is undefined, i.e. it does not contain a colon, then `$var` will still be assigned `$line[0]`, since `undef` will be converted to `0`, with a warning. If `use warnings` is not in effect, this error is silent, and therefore insidious.

This code seems to be written by someone who does not know too much about perl, and it might not be very safe to use.

Comment: It's old-school Perl - say from the late-90s.

Comment: Surely even old school perl could open a file for reading in a normal fashion.

Comment: As in 'instead of using `cat`'?  Yes; even old-school Perl could open a file directly for reading and the [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) is pointless.  You're (or, at least, I'm) never quite sure whether stuff like that has been simplified.  (I also noted that it was a piped input, but didn't notice that it was UUOC, when I first read the code.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler UUOC, that's cute. I'll have to remember that one. :)

Comment: @TLP Randal used to issue UUOC "awards" in comp.unix.(questions|shell) years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution trims leading [whitespace](http://p3rl.org/perlrecharclass#Whitespace) that appears at the beginning of the line ([`^`](http://p3rl.org/perlre#Metacharacters)), leaving any non-whitespace characters as the first.

The [`||` operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop#C-style-Logical-Or) in `open... || die ...` is a high-precedence **or**.  If [`open`](http://p3rl.org/open) fails, [`die`](http://p3rl.org/die) executes.

`open(FILE, "cat $fileName |")` is a waste of an external process.  To read a file for input, simply do:

```
open FILE, '<', $filename or die qq{Could not open "$filename" for reading: $!};
```

The parentheses for the `open` call are optional because [`or`](http://p3rl.org/op#Logical-or%2c-Defined-or%2c-and-Exclusive-Or) does not bind tightly.

It is also better to use lexical file handles:

```
open my $fh, '<' $filename or die qq{Could not open "$filename" for reading: $!};
```

This file handle is assigned to a lexical variable that lives only within the scope it is declared.  Once the program flow exits this scope, the file closes automatically.

Comment: Actually, `||` is a high-precedence version of (the much newer) `or`.  The function-call notation for `open` with parentheses is necessary to avoid confusion when `||` is used.  The code is quite old, using the two-argument form of `open` and not using a lexical file handle.  There should be a `close FILE` lurking around too.

Comment: Also, consider not using global filehandles. See "[Don't Open Files in the old way](http://szabgab.com/open-files-in-the-old-way.html)".

Comment: @jonathanLeffler: Corrected with thanks --- thinking upside down :-)